# OrientDB REST: How to create an Edge class?

Tags: rest, orientdb

I'm looking for a way to create a custom edge class by using the REST API of OrientDB.

I couldn't find a way to specify the SuperClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE CLASS <class-name> EXTENDS E` sql command via HTTP: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html  and https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Class.html